# Monitor remote PC shutdown activities

Tags: windows-7, remote-access

We have 10 Windows 7 PC's which are mainly used for builds

We have some issue that the server is shutting down by itself due to reasons which we cannot identify. In the event viewer I see the "Kernel power down" events. Not lot of information here

I did a RAM test using Mem86 and there are no errors.

I am looking of a monitoring mechanism which would inform me (email) when the PC is shut down.

I have following ideas/options

- Ping all the machines and any one of them is down, send email
- Write a file to a location with uptime every 10 mins

Are there any other fail proof methods to monitor the heartbeat?

I don't have the privilege to install any 3rd party software

Comment: you can always write a script to monitor your machines.  or use a slew of monitoring products.  Moving to the cloud (AWS for example) would get you this monitoring for free

Comment: well these machines are in our corporate intranet. So scripting is my only option I guess

Comment: there is a slew of monitoring products... something simple like nagios/icinga/datadog/copperegg/appdynamics?  Take my advice with a grain of salt.  have not had to use windows in over a decade

Comment: Thanks..unfortunately I cannot use these due to our software usage restrictions. I will check them anyways

Comment: 1. What does this mean: "We have 10 Windows 7 PC's which are mainly used for builds"? What are these builds and how are they relevant to the problem? 2. What does this mean: "We have some issue that the server is shutting down by itself"? What does the server have to do with the workstations? 3. What does this mean: "Are there any other fail proof methods to monitor the heartbeat"? What heartbeat are you referring to?

Comment: When your software usage restrictions prevent you from doing your job, then it is time to get rid of the software usage restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use Powershell:

```
$computerArray = "PCOne", "PCTwo"  #List of Computers to check
Foreach ($computer in $computerArray)
    {
        If (!(Test-Connection $computer -Quiet)) #test if the computer responds to a ping
            {Send-MailMessage -To address@place.com -Subject "$computer is down"} #If not, send an email            
    }
```

Fill in your email information and put the script in a scheduled task and you should be good to go.

Comment: tried in Perl but able to ping only Linux machines. Windows machines always returns 0 `#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;
my $host;
my @host_array;
my $p;
open my $fh, "<",  "server_config.ini" or die "Could not open file";
@host_array=readline($fh);
close $fh;
chomp @host_array;
$p = Net::Ping->new();
#print $p->ping($machine_to_ping);
my $retval;
foreach $host (@host_array)
{
    print "$host is ";
    print "NOT " unless $p->ping($host);
    print " reachable.\n";    
}`